# Functional series in python?

Tags: python

Want to plot function defined with series

```
f = lambda x: s(1.0/N*x)+s(2.0/N*x)+s(3.0/N*x)
p.plotFunc(f)
```

this code doesn't plot right like above

```
def funsum(f1,f2):
    return ( lambda x: (f1(x)+f2(x)) )

N = 4
f = lambda x: 0.0
for n in xrange(1,N):
    fn = lambda x: s(n/float(N)*x)
    fs = funsum(f,fn)
    f = fs
p.plotFunc(f)
```

Comment: What is `p.plotFunc`?

Comment: it just plots any function f of one real numeric variable on bitmap p.

Comment: "doesn't plot right" Please tell use what you expect. It is hard to answer your question if we don't knwo what you try to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're having problems with closures.  Ultimately, your problem boils down to these 2 lines:

```
for n in xrange(1,N):
    fn = lambda x: s(n/float(N)*x)
```

The issue here is that `fn` holds a *reference* to `n`.  The *value* of that reference doesn't get evaluated *until the function is called* -- presumably in `plotFunc`.  So, when `plotFunc` calls all of these lambda functions that you're passing around, they all end up with the terminal value for `n` in the loop (in this case 3).

e.g.:

```
>>> x, y, z = ['x'], ['y'], ['z']
>>> funcs = [lambda: i for i in (x, y, z)]
>>> funcs[0]()
['z']
>>> funcs[1]()
['z']
>>> funcs[2]()
['z']
>>> funcs[2] is funcs[0]  # Note that they are different functions
False
>>>
```

There are a few solutions, but the simplest is to make `n` a default argument (that you never pass) since default arguments are evaluated at the time the function is created, not at the time that it gets called.

e.g.:

```
fn = lambda x, n=n: s(n/float(N)*x)
```

Comment: +1 for a good guess, but really OP should be more explicit in their question.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid -- definitely agree.  I spent much longer than I should have needed to trying to guess at what the problem was (especially with how convoluted this code is).  Ultimately, (after ignoring the plot function that I've never seen before) -- I'm pretty sure the question boils down to why the top function doesn't produce the same output as the bottom one and I _think_ that is because of the closure problem ...